# Android app crashes with getMDCPropertyMap : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, logback, slf4j, logback-classic

My android app has crashed with following stack for a certain user.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.getMDCPropertyMap (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.subAppend (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus (Unknown Source)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info (Unknown Source)
  at com.my.app.ApplicationEx.onCreate (ApplicationEx.java:156)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1014)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4753)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1343)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5590)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

This crash has only occurred to a single user (Samsung Galaxy Tab E 9.6 (gtelwifi), Android 4.4). This does not re-produce in other devices.

I use slf4j for logging in my android app and this is how I have imported the logging libraries.

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.3.0-2'
```

What could be the reason for this crash?

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce this?

Comment: @tony19 Thanks for looking into this. There is no certain way to reproduce this. Only two users have reported this. First user reported it couple of months back and I can't remember what the device is. Second user says that the app used to work earlier, but suddenly stopped working. This could have triggered due to a recent update I did to android sdk version 28.